# ASP.NET MVC + ORACLE + Entity Framework Error : Unable to generate an explicit migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I'm in Visaul Studio Profesional 15.9.3, APS.NET MVC framework 4.8 with a Oracle DB Express 11G and entity framework 6.2.0. When I enable my migration everything works fine and I can do my first migration 'add-migration Initial' and Update it 'update-database'.

All the tables appear correctly on my DB but when I want to do another migration *I have this error*: **Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201812181830095_Initial]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.**

**In my Console:**

```
PM> enable-migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project project.Web.
PM> add-migration Initial -verbose
Using StartUp project 'project.Web'.
Using NuGet project 'project.Web'.
Scaffolding migration 'Initial'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration Initial' again.
Target database is: '' (DataSource: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE))), Provider: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client, Origin: Configuration).
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201812181830095_Initial].
Applying explicit migration: 201812181830095_Initial.
Running Seed method.
PM> add-migration Add-Desc-Name
Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201812181830095_Initial]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.
```

What can possibly happen to make me having this kind of error?

My first migration and update always work but the second don't.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you check your database on `__MigrationHistory` table to see if it have the entry for `201812181830095_Initial`?

Comment: Yes and it is there! from db _MigrationHistory -> 201812181830095_Initial Project.Web.Migrations.Configuration (BLOB) 6.2.0-61023